# pci-passthru in Ubuntu KVM 14.04.2 on ppc64el

Tags: kvm-virtualization, pci

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04.2 for ppc64.  Is pci passthrough work on this version?  We're using Mellanox nics.

- pci-assign:

echo "0006:01:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/pci-stub/bind
qemu-system-ppc64le -k fr -daemonize --enable-kvm -vga none -m 4096 -cpu 
host -smp 16,cores=2,threads=8 -serial telnet::41014,server,nowait 
-serial null -monitor telnet::52025,server,nowait -device 
pci-assign,host=0006:01:00.0 -display none -mem-path /mnt/huge -kernel 
/root/test/vmlinux

Qemu fails on following error:
qemu-system-ppc64: -device pci-assign,host=0006:01:00.0: 
'kvm-pci-assign' is not a valid device model name

- vfio-pci:
  echo "0006:01:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/bind
  qemu-system-ppc64le -k fr -daemonize --enable-kvm -vga none -m 4096 -cpu 
  host -smp 16,cores=2,threads=8 -serial telnet::41014,server,nowait 
  -serial null -monitor telnet::52025,server,nowait -devicevfio-pci 
  ,host=0006:01:00.0 -display none -mem-path /mnt/huge -kernel 
  /root/test/vmlinux

Here the VM is able to boot but when inserting mlx4_core module, the VM 
freeze. The last trace we can see from the driver is in mlx4_init_fw().